# Use PRE_SUBMIT EventListener in AbstractType Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, addeventlistener

I try to get data from an EventListener in an AbstractType custom class using `FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT`, but data returns empty fields, if I use `FormEvents::SUBMIT`, fields get data, but I can't add fields.

Do you know why `$form->getData()` returns empty fields?

My class is:

```
class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)    
    {
        $builder
            ->add('extra', ExtraType::class, array(
                'data_class' => ExtraForm::class
            ))
            ->add('sales', SalesType::class, array(
                'data_class' => SalesForm::class
            ));

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $data = $form->getData();

            //Fields in data are empty
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r( $data );
            echo '</pre>';

            /*
            Example:
            AppBundle\Entity\User Object
            (
                [id:protected] => 
                [userType:protected] => 
                [sales:protected] => 
                [extra:protected] => 
                [username:protected] => 
                [usernameCanonical:protected] => 
                [email:protected] => 
            )
            */

            //CODE
        });
    }

    //CODE
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `PRE_SUBMIT` is called before the data is submitted to the form. This is why `$form->getData()` is empty when `PRE_SUBMIT` is triggered. [The doc says](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html):

> The `FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT` event is dispatched at the beginning of the `Form::submit()` method.
>
> It can be used to:
>
> - Change data from the request, before submitting the data to the form;
> - Add or remove form fields, before submitting the data to the form.

If you want to access the data you need to do it directly in the `FormEvent` parameter sent to the event handler. In your case that's `$event->getData()`.

See [FormEvent and its getData() method in the API](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/Form/FormEvent.html).